# Unable to send object to NodeRED

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send the following to NodeRED..

```
this.user= {

         medName1: '',
         medTime1: ''
         },
         {
         medName2: '',
         medTime2: ''
         },
         {
         medName3: '',
         medTime3: ''
    };

    this.register = function() {
       console.log('User clicked register', this.user);
       $scope.sock.send(this.user);
    };
```

The register() is called after I click on "submit" button.

The problem is that whenever I try to send this.user to NodeRED via a websocket connectivity, I get [object Object] shown in NodeRED. I've already read answers related to [object Object] but none of them address this problem.

How do I resolve this? Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what if you make `this.user` an array?

```
this.user= [{

         medName1: '',
         medTime1: ''
         },
         {
         medName2: '',
         medTime2: ''
         },
         {
         medName3: '',
         medTime3: ''
         }
    ];

    this.register = function() {
       console.log('User clicked register', this.user);
       $scope.sock.send(this.user);
    };
```

Comment: It's not working. The array element at index 0 is still getting converted to string [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.user` into `Array` like this

```
this.user= [
         {
         medName: '',
         medTime: ''
         },
         {
         medName: '',
         medTime: ''
         },
         {
         medName: '',
         medTime: ''
         }
    ];

this.register = function() {
   console.log('User clicked register', this.user);
   $scope.sock.send(this.user);
};
```

You can obtenir the first user by `this.user[0]`.

Then you can obtenir the `medName` of the first user by `this.user[0].medName`, which should be a `string`.

If you want to convert `this.user` into a `string`, try the [Array toString Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp).

```
var userString = this.user.toString();
```

Or you can convert `this.user` into `json`

```
JSON.stringify(this.user)
```

Comment: It's not working. The array element at index 0 is still getting converted to string [object Object]

Comment: Yes, you can get the medName of 1st user by this.user[0].medName, and it will be a string

Comment: Yes, this.user[0].medName can be done, but I want to send the entire array content to NodeRED. The join() method too converts the array into the form [object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

Comment: try the Array toString Method.

    var userString = this.user.toString();

Comment: toString() also returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: I understand what you want ! Convert the array to a json !  try JSON.stringify(this.user)

Comment: I tested it, it will return a string [{"medName":"","medTime":""},{"medName":"","medTime":""},{"medName":"","medTime":""}]

Comment: OK, so this is working!. One thing I forgot to mention (and I am sorry for this) was that medName and medTime take input from a form I have in HTML. The entire array does go to NodeRED now but without the values assigned to those variables. I tried doing var userstring = JSON.stringify(this.user); inside the register() but the result is still the same. This is how the result looks now [{"medName1":"","medTime1":""},{"medName2":"","medTime2":""},{"medName3":"","medTime3":""}]